# why doesn't ::after work when trying to change css background?

Tags: html, css

I have the following problem, Im trying to make a navigation bar with ul in django with css using a background image. The problem is that I want its opacity to be 0.5, but when I do it, the words also gain opacity, which I don't want. So I read that if I use a "pseudo-element" (using ::after in the ul) I could raise the opacity of the background without affecting the words. I used the content:"" variable.

```
ul{    
margin: -0.5em 0 0 -0.5em;
width: 82.5em;    
}
ul::after{
content:"";
background-image:url("fondo.jpg");
opacity: 0.5; 
}
```

The problem is that after doing it, the ul doesn't load the background, but if I put the background-image in the ul one (without the ::after), it does. Im clearly very noob at this, hehe, thanks!

[image: What i get when I put the image in ::after]

[image: What I want to get, when I put the image in ul, but if I change its opacity, I also change the words]

The first picture is what I get when I put the image in the ::after.
The second is what I get when I put it in ul. But if I change its opacity, I also change the words.

Comment: Your CSS code only works in context of the HTML, so please post the relevant parts of the HTML as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `linear-gradient` like:

```
background-image: linear-gradient( to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)), url("fondo.jpg");
```

Here you change the `0.8` to the opacity of the background you want.